# can i novnc to ubuntu docker via pod

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, novnc

I'm using the

```
docker run -p 6081:6081 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc
docker run -p 6081:443 -e SSL_PORT=443 -v ${PWD}/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc
```

I can access the docker from https://localhost:6081 in encrypted but cannot manage to operate it via deployment for kubernetes

my deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc 
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
        env:
        - name: RESOLUTION
          value: "1920x1080"
        - name: SSL_PORT
          value: "443"
```

how can i refer my local ssl from my deployment to the kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create **TLS SECRETS** as mentioned in doc[1] with your cert data and you can either refer the created secret as a ENV VAR or mount it inside the pod.

[1] - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets

Comment: so create secret in k8s and after that mount the secret  folder in deployment right?

Comment: Yes you are right !!!